# Loading CSS/JS files when redirecting to next view

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I want my users to be able to click a `button` on the front-end of my website, and be redirected to my `page-login.php`.

I'm pretty much doing it, but I'm missing some things, because it doesn't load my CSS or JS files. Even though if I set that page into my main page, it will load everything alright.

This is the error message:

> GET http://localhost/projeto/index.php/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found).

This happens to CSS, JS files, images, etc.

First of all:

- I think that I need to insert my controller and view on the routes page, am I right? If so, how?
- The way I call my Controller is messing up the way the page appears. What's the right way?

This is my code:

- Main page HTML:

  ```
  href="index.php/login_controller"
  ```
- login_controller:

  ```
  public function index (){

      $this->load->view('Main/page_login');
  }
  ```

So, what am I missing? Is anything that I said true?

Answer (score 0):

Find the config.php file in the `/application/config` folder.  Edit this file and find:

```
$config['base_url'] =
```

You should add here correct path. In your current situation you have to add:  `http://localhost/projeto/`

so this line must be:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projeto/';
```

You should include the URL helper into your autoload configuration.  `/application/config/autoload.php`  add `'url'` into `$autoload['helper']` array:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array( 'url');
```

after that you can refer your CSS, img, JS and other files with `base_url()` function. For example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/favicon.png"/>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('favicon.png');?>" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect(base_url() . 'login_controller/index', 'refresh');